# Number of WCU equal to number of items to write in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have been struggling to understand the meaning of WCU in AWS DynamoDB Documentation. What I understood from AWS documentation is that

> If your application needs to write 1000 items where each item is of
>   size 0.2KB then you need to provision 1000 WCU (i.e. 0.2/1 = 0.2 which
>   makes nearest 1KB, so 1000 items(to write) * 1KB() = 1000WCU)

If my above understanding is correct then I am wondering for those applications who requires to write millions of records in to DynamoDB per second, Do those application needs to provision that many millions of WCU?

Appreciate if you could clarify me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used DynamoDB in past (and experienced scaling out the RCU and WCU for my application) and according to AWS docs :-

> One write capacity unit represents one write per second for an item up
>   to 1 KB in size. If you need to write an item that is larger than 1
>   KB, DynamoDB will need to consume additional write capacity units. The
>   total number of write capacity units required depends on the item
>   size.

So it means, if you writing a document which is of size 4.5 KB, than it will consume 5 WCU, **DyanamoDB** roundoff it to next integer number.

Also your understanding

> here each item is of size 0.2KB then you need to provision 1000 WCU
>   (i.e. 0.2/1 = 0.2 which makes nearest 1KB, so 1000 items(to write) *
>   1KB() = 1000WCU).

**is correct.**

To save the WCU, unit you need to design your system in such a way that your document size is always near to round-off.

Note :- To avoid the large cost associated with DynamoDB, if you are having lots of reads, you can use caching on top of dynamoDB, which is also suggested by them and was implemented by us as well.(If your application is write heavy, than this approach will not work and you should consider some other alternative like Elasticsearch etc).

According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html doc , see below thing

> A caching solution can mitigate the skewed read activity for popular
>   items. In addition, since it reduces the amount of read activity
>   against the table, caching can help reduce your overall costs for
>   using DynamoDB.